# How do I print a vector of vectors of string in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print a vector of vectors of strings, by moving the logic to a function. My program is compiling normally, but it does not print my vectors.

This is the function call on main:

```
showInst(vectInst);
```

This is the prototype in .hpp:

```
void showInst(vector<vector<string>> vectInst);
```

Here is the implementation .cpp:

```
void showInst(vector<vector<string>> vectInst) {
    for(i=0; i<vectInst.size(); i++){
        for(j=0; j<vectInst[i].size(); j++){
            cout << vectInst[i][j];
        }
    }
 }
```

This one is the prototype of the function that receives the vector of vector to initialize it

```
void initInst(vector<vector<string>> vectInst, int numbInst);
```

This is the .cpp

```
void initInst(vector<vector<string>> vectInst, int numbInst) {
    int i, j;
    string inst;

    for(i=0; i<numbInst; i++){
        vector<string> vect;
        for(j=0; j<4; j++){
            cin >> inst;
            vect.push_back(inst); 
        }

        vectInst.push_back(vect);
    }

}
```

Call on the main:

```
vector<vector<string>> vectInst;

initInst(vectInst, 2);
```

Comment: What does it print?

Comment: Nothing! The program compiles normally, but doesn't print anything

Comment: Try adding `cout << endl;` after the loops to flush the output.

Comment: It appears you are at least looping over the vectors correctly. Either the vectors are empty or something is causing the output to not be displayed per @JonDeaton's suggestion

Comment: show the code that populates the vector

Comment: show the full code that's affecting `vectInst`

Comment: @JonDeaton I've already tried to add the **cout << endl;**, but it doesn't work

Comment: @ItaloHortiz what does `vectInst.size()` prints?

Comment: Not related to the issue, but `vector<vector<string>> vectInst` should be changed to `const vector<vector<string>> &vectInst`. You are passing `vectInst` by value, so you are making copies of all the vectors, which you don't need to do.  Pass `vectInst` by reference instead.

Comment: @ItaloHortiz can you edit your question to include the additional code?

Comment: @ItaloHortiz that's unreadable, please include it in the question

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri changing `>>` to `> >` is not required in C++11 onwards. The C++11 standard specifically addresses that issue.

Comment: ohh, thanks for this information :)

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

First in function `showInst`: don't pass your vector by value: this produces an useless copy of every single string/vector. Use a const reference instead:

```
void showInst(vector<vector<string>> const & vectInst);
```

The code of the function is correct, although we'd prefer for-range loops:

```
for (auto const & string_vec : vectInst) {
    for (auto const & str : string_vec) {
        cout << str;
    }
}
```

Your vector is probably empty, or maybe this function isn't even called. The problem must be somewhere else.
I suggest you print some brackets at the beginning and end of this function.

#### After edition

Your vector is indeed empty as you are (also) passing it by value in `initInst` function. This is a local copy you are modifing, not the original.

Pass it by reference:

```
void initInst(vector<vector<string>> & vectInst, int numbInst) {
                                     ^
```

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @SidS How so please?

Comment: It doesn't address his problem.  Your helpful suggestions should be comments.

Answer (score 0):

`initInst()` is modifying a copy of the `vector` you declare in `main()`.  To make it modify the `vector` you have in `main()`, you need to pass it by reference rather than by value.

Change this:

```
void initInst(vector<vector<string>> vectInst, int numbInst) {
```

To this:

```
void initInst(vector<vector<string>> &vectInst, int numbInst) {
```